# Spring Transactions not working - JDBCTemplate is reading uncommitted data

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

The following Method inserts two records (but doesn't commits them at this point) and it then tries to read one of the uncommitted records from the previous statements. I wrapped the code with Transaction, and set the isolationLevel to "READ_COMMITTED" but this doesn't seems to be working. The read/"SELECT" statement is reading the uncommitted records.

How is this possible? Where am I going wrong? Please see the code below and help me out. I would be really thankful ~

**Note :** 

I am using **BoneCP** to get the DataSource. 
***dbConnectionPool.initConnectionPool(dbName)*** , will fetch a BoneCPDataSource.

> ```
>  @Override public void testDBCalls() {
>   dBConnectionPool.initConnectionPool("titans");      
>   DataSource dataSource = dBConnectionPool.getDataSource("titans");   
>   DefaultTransactionDefinition definition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
>
>   definition.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED);
>   definition.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ);
>   definition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
>
>   DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);      TransactionStatus
>   transactionStatus = txManager.getTransaction(definition);
>
>   try {           
>         try {
>
>           JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
>
>           String sql = "INSERT INTO groundwater(external_id,source_type) VALUES (12, 13);";
>           jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
>           System.out.println("Successfully inserted - 1");
>
>           String sql2 = "INSERT INTO groundwater(external_id, source_type,) VALUES(123,45);";
>           jdbcTemplate.update(sql2);
>           System.out.println("Successfully inserted - 2");
>
>           String sql3 = "select gw_id from groundwater where external_id= 123;";
>           System.out.println("Result : "+jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql3));
>
>           txManager.commit(transactionStatus);
>           System.out.println("Commiting the trasaction...");
>
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>           txManager.rollback(transactionStatus);
>           System.out.println("Rolling back the transaction");
>
>       }
>   } finally {
>       try {
>           dataSource.getConnection().close();
>           System.out.println("Closing the connection ...");       
>         } catch (SQLException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();            
>         }
>     }
>  }
> ```

Comment: And why shouldn't it  work. You are indeed not committing any thing but everything is run from a single transaction, a transaction can always see the changes it made.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do SQL Transactions Work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668166/how-do-sql-transactions-work)

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! Got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @M.Denium explained in the comment, I was trying to do everything from a single transaction. Isolation Levels are meant for maintaining consistency across different transactions. I was still learning the concepts, so I took it in a wrong way.